# How to validate @NoNull first then @AssertTrue after

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lombok, javax.validation

I am trying to validate a simple DTO:

```java
@Data
public class Dto {

    @NotNull
    private Integer anInt;

    @AssertTrue
    public boolean isIntCustomValid() {
        return anInt == 123 || anInt == 999;
    }

}
```

In my Controller, with @Valid. When `anInt` is null, `isIntCustomValid` is still validated and I get this error because `anInt` is null:

```
HV000090: Unable to access
```

If I remove `isIntCustomValid`, then @NotNull works correctly.
I want to validate these separately.

I tried using `@GroupSequence` and `@Groups`, which works, but I have to create empty marker interfaces which is does not seem like an elegant solution.

Comment: GroupSequence is a correct approach if you want to validate not all in once but by portions. You need these empty interface markers

Answer (score 0):

If you got `HV000090`, then should be handle exceptions like this:
[Link][1]

```java
@AssertTrue
public boolean isIntCustomValid() { 
    if( (Objects.nonNull(anInt) ) {
           return anInt == 123 || anInt == 999; 
    } 
    return true;
}


 [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Jpr.jpg
```

Comment: https://github.com/upendra-rai/github-error-page/blob/main/JavaValidationError.java